# Drupal 6: display image with View in blog posts listing page

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-6, module, cck

I'm new at Drupal, love it so far :)

I added Photo and Logo File field to blog entry with CCK. I need to display these images at blog post listing page. So at View Module, I added fields as below;

**At View:**

```
Content: Logo URL to file

Content: Photo Path to file
```

and it displays only names of files, but I need to display image. how can I make it with View Module?

**Blog Listing Page:**

> Logo:
>   http://blabla.com/drupal/sites/default/files/Logo_0.jpeg
>
> Photo:
>   sites/default/files/photoname_0.jpeg

Appreciate helps!!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views in adding field select field like: "Content: Image (field_image)", then in **Format**: Image, Image to linked node etc.

Recommend also install imagecache module for appropriate resizing image.

Comment: you again :) thanks a lot! I was using FileField Module for photo, thats was the problem as I found out. Just sorted out the problem that I supposed to use imagefield module : ) thanks for reply. so now downloading imagecache as well. :)